# Where query with Time.now

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to achieve the following:

```
Model.where("asdasd = ? AND to <= ?", nil, Time.now).each do |model|
```

I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "to": syntax error: SELECT "bla".* FROM "table" WHERE (asdasd = NULL AND to <= '2015-11-09 10:18:14.777643')
```

I also use the same in another controller, where I get the same error. What would be the correct way to achieve what I want? I am also quite sure that it worked already like that, could there be any other thing which causes this issue?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TO` is an SQL keyword, and needs to be quoted in a query. the list of SQLite keywords is avaiable in the [SQLite documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

Other database engines have similar (but not identical) rules and lists of keywords, so if you change from SQLite then check the rules for whatever the new engine is.